# FCM Notification how to send image using php?

Tags: php, android, curl

Want to send notification with image for that i use following code but still it is not working properly

```
{
    $msg = array
    (
        'body'  => 'here is a message. message',
        'title'     => 'This is a title',
        'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'icon'  => 'url_image',
        'image' => 'url_image'
    );
    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => array('id1','id2'),
        'notification'          => $msg,

    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=my_serverkey',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'url of fcm ' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
}
```

I get notification without image

what is solution for it?

Comment: You have a dangling quote issue in this code. See the code colour

Comment: `'registration_ids'  => array('id1',id2'),` < here

Comment: Is that in the real code you are running?

Comment: In my code I used like this then also it is not sending image in notification     'registration_ids' => array('id1','id2'),

Comment: did you found a solution ?